# Earbuds only work after restart

Tags: audio, headphones, headphone-jack, earbuds

I'm having a wierd problem with my laptop not recognizing when I plug my earbuds into the jack unless I restart first. If the computer is already turned on when I plug them in, nothing happens - sound plays through the laptop speaker. If I plug the earbuds in and restart, then they will work. If I unplug them after restarting and plug them back in, they don't work.

Everything I have read online tells me to check what devices are enabled in the sound settings, but unless I restart, the earbuds don't show up even after looking for devices. After restarting, they are selected like they should be.

I've tested the earbuds on other devices and they work. I have a set of headphones that plug in to the USB, and those also work (I don't want to just use these because they are too big to carry around). I took the back off a while back to replace the hard drive and it is possible I broke something, although I don't think so. Any ideas on how to fix this?